# Automatically prepend std:: to cout, etc. in Visual Studio for C++ and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2008, eclipse-juno

EDIT:  Added "and Eclipse" to title and into body pf the question.  Need it in both places.

**I know "Thou shalt not "using"" in good C++ so...**

How might I add a tool (enable some existing tool) in MS Visual Studio 2008 (VC++) and/or Eclipse Juno to allow me to type `cout` and as soon as I press the space bar, or maybe `<`, have the editor replace the `cout` with `std::cout`.

Can I extend this to all `std::` items?

Can such a tool recognize that the `cout` is in "code" space and not in "comment" space or "quoted string" space?

Comment: I found [this question](http://www.scansource.com/en/Products%20and%20Promotions/Manufacturer/Family/Product.aspx?pid=LOG-KB1700U-IN-BK) helpful.  Sadly it is per item, meaning I have to add a completion proposal for `cout`, another for `string`, still another for `endl`, etc. ad nauseum.  I'm betting `string`, `cout`, `endl` and one or two others will cover 90% of the casers!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `using namespace std;` to the top of your file, after the `#include`s, to implicitly add `std::`.
The text of your code will not change (that is, the compiler won't go and textually pre-pend `std::` to everywhere) but it will know to look in the `std` namespace for symbols it can't find elsewhere.

Comment: THOU SHALT NOT "USING", see the OP and a million postings in this forum explaining why.